# How to get the last element in a list in R

Tags: r, list, sapply

I want to get the every last element in a list. I have found that by using sapply function, the first element can be obtained.

```
sapply(a,`[`,1)
```

However, I don't actually understantd what is the meaning of `[`, and how to get the last element in a similar way. This code doesn't work.

```
sapply(a,`]`,1)
```

Comment: `sapply(a, tail, 1)`

Comment: The `[` is a reference to the indexing operation. It's just what gets called when you do `a[1]`

Comment: ``mapply(`[`, a, lengths(a))``

Comment: When you call `a[1]` the parser interprets it as `'['(a,1)`, you could see the former as a mere shortcut.The function `]` doesn't exist. You can use the function `[` directly, in practice I believe it is useful only when passing it as an argument like you did in your example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I came here with the same question, and saw that the answer must have been overlooked, but for me @akrun as usual had the answer that worked for me. So in the absence of a correct answer it is:

`sapply(a, tail, 1)`

Answer (score 7):

**By using the length of a list/vector:**

```
a[length(a)]
```

**For the last "n"th element:**

```
a[length(a)-n+1]
```

**Example:**

```
a[length(a)-1] #the 2nd last element
a[length(a)-2] #the 3rd last element
a[length(a)-8] #the 9th last element
```

Answer (score -3):

If I get your query correctly, it could simply be :

```
tail(a, n = 1)
```